# Proof that $f(c)=f(c+1)$ on a continuous function

Tags: calculus, functions, continuity, proof-writing

Hi I'm stuck on this question on my homework sheet:

"Let $f : [0,2] → \mathbb R$ be a continuous function with $f(0) = f(2)$. Show that there is some $c \in [0, 1]$ with $f (c) = f (c + 1)$"

I thought initially I could do proof by induction but then I realised that the function is continuous. So I then thought that I could use the fixed point theorem but then I had no idea what to do.

Any help with this would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Consider $$g(x) = f(x+1) - f(x)$$ and note $$g(0) = f(1) - f(0)$$ 

$$g(1) = f(2) - f(1) = f(0) - f(1) = -g(0)$$

Answer (score 4):

Define $\overline{f}(x) := f(x) - f(x+1)$ then $\overline{f}(0) = f(0) - f(1)$ and $\overline{f}(1) = f(1) - f(2) = -(f(0) - f(1)) = -\overline{f}(0)$ and $\overline{f}$ is continuous.

Now consider the 3 cases:

1.) $\overline{f}(0) = 0 \Rightarrow c=0$

2.) $\overline{f}(0) < 0 \Rightarrow \overline{f}(1) = -\overline{f}(0) > 0$ and use intermediate value theorem.

3.) $\overline{f}(0) > 0 \Rightarrow \overline{f}(1) = -\overline{f}(0) < 0$ and use intermediate value theorem.

Comment: "mid value theorem" = intermediate value theorem https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intermediate_value_theorem

Comment: Thx, edited the post.